# giving properties to webadresses

Tags: php, javascript, css

I need to set some style property for webpages. Is there a way to assign this to all the adresses with /index.php/projecten/ instead of putting all of the complete adresses in the code? I'm using the following code:

```
<ul class="subnavlist" style="display: <?php echo (
 !in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],  
      array(
          '/index.php/projecten/wonen.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/werken.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/infrastructuur.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/winkel-en-dorpcentra.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/parken-en-groen.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/recreatie.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/stedenbouw.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/objecten.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/werken/vitalisering-zuidspoor.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/werken/uitbreiding-venekoten.html',
          '/index.php/projecten/werken/herstructurering-tatelaar.html'
       )
   )
)? "none" : "block"; ?>" id="sub1">
```

Comment: Just an unrelated but important topic. Are you able to put `..` in the path and access other files? What happens if you visit `/index.php/index.php`?

Comment: I get a 404 category not found error

Comment: Okay fine. Many people decide to write a PHP script which will just echo a file's contents and that can be a massive security problem. Just checking that you did not do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php)

```
if substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,strlen('/index.php/projecten/')) != "/index.php/projecten/") {
  echo "none";
} else {
  echo "block";
}
```